# Restrict sorting of elements in Original list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 2 sortable lists. A and B. When I drag an element from A and hover it over A, the elements in A are moved due to the placeholder.

I do not want the elements in A to be sortable. I just want to drag it from A to B and be able to sort it within B before dropping the element.

I do not wish to set the placeholder to hidden as it will make it difficult to see where it item will be dropped in B.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What I got from your explanation is that you want to be able to drag an item from list A to list B, but not vise versa. You also only want the items in list B to be sortable, not list A.

Considering that, here is what I came up with:

```js
$('.list-A').on('mousedown', function() {
  // only allow the active item to be sortable
  $(this).sortable('option', 'items', $(this).find('.item:active'));
}).sortable({
  connectWith: '.list-B'
});

$('.list-B').sortable({
  items: '.item'
});
```

```css
.sortable-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  background: #AF1843;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="sortable-list list-A">
      <li class="item">list A1</li>
      <li class="item">list A2</li>
      <li class="item">list A3</li>
      <li class="item">list A4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="sortable-list list-B">
      <li class="item">list B1</li>
      <li class="item">list B2</li>
      <li class="item">list B3</li>
      <li class="item">list B4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Souleste/kdcmp098/)